# Change PDO in mysqli

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I changed the connection type of the PDO in mysqli.

**PDO_conection**

```
<?php
try {
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=exercise', 'root', 'root');
} catch (PDOException $e){
exit('Datebase error.');
}
?>
```

**mysqli_conection**

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "exercise";
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Error: Could not connect to database.";
exit;
}
?>
```

And now trying to piece of code written in the PDO change in mysqli.

**PDO_code**

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name=? AND user_password=? LIMIT 1");
        $query->bindValue(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(2, $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
        $num = $query->rowCount();
        $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and this is my attempt to change that in mysqli

**mysqli_code**

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name=? AND user_password=? LIMIT 1");
    $query->bind_result($username, $password);
        $query->execute();
        $num = $query->num_rows;
    $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
```

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: This is a rare transition. I am eager to know why one would want so? Besides that. Your mysqli code is just wrong. You need to get yourself a tutorial and **follow** it.

Comment: First of this looks absolutely terrible "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name=? AND user_password=?", I'm not gonna bash about selecting all columns, but selecting by user name and password looks really shady. Why not just get the password from user where username = post/get username, and then use the php password function to compare it? On topic: do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an issue:

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name=? AND user_password=? LIMIT 1");
$query->bind_result($username, $password);//<==
$query->execute();
$num = $query->num_rows;
$row = $query->fetch_assoc();
```

Bind result binds the passed variables to the result set, whereas you wanted [`bind_param`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

```
$query->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
```

You will still have to use th `bind_result` after that, and forget about `fetch_assoc`. A `mysqli_stmt` only has a `fetch` method:

```
$query->bind_result($id, $field2);//one var per table field...
while($query->fetch())
{
    echo $id.', '.$field1;
}
```

I think it's pretty obvious why `SELECT *` isn't to be recommended...

Also, for consistency, change `mysqli_connection_error()` to `if ($mysqli->connect_error)` or something. `mysqli_*` offers both procedural and OO style, but please, don't mix the two.
According to the docs, you can't use this, as YourCommonSense pointed out to me, because it was broken until PHP 5.2.9 and 5.3.0. It's recommended to keep the procedural check to ensure compatibility.

So in full:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT id FROM users WHER user_name = ? AND user_password = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id);
//or, in your case
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$numRows = $result->num_rows;
```

Use the `get_result`, `save_result`, `free_result`,... methods, and from there on, use the `mysqli_result` instance you get from the statement, [which has all the goodies you're after](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)

Comment: Please take a time and try to run the code you wrote. Then learn that most of your suggestions are plainly wrong.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Ok, fair enough. I'm not all too familiar with `mysqli_*`, but I'm trying a few things with `mysqli_result` ATM. Didn't know about that, to be honest, so I'll get back to this answer once I find out more

Comment: Better now. `mysqli_connection_error() to if ($mysqli->connect_error)` is also a thing to try.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Thx, I did touch on `connection_error` as a property in my first edit. BTW: I'm beginning to see why you're an advocate for the `mysqli_*` extension, I must say. (Not sure if you really _are_ a fan of `mysqli_*`, but you've posted stuff about it before)

Comment: `mysqli_connection_error() to if ($mysqli->connect_error)` is also a thing to try **and see it never works**

Comment: @YourCommonSense: the docs say it was broken until PHP 5.3, I'm running 5.4... will edit, though

Comment: If you fail with creating an object, there will be no properties at all. While an API function always exists. Sometimes we have to sacrifice aesthetics in favor of working code.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: That's how they fixed the `connect_error` property: by forcing the constructor to return an instance, even if connecting failed: _"OO syntax only: If a connection fails an object is still returned. To check if the connection failed then use either the mysqli_connect_error() function or the mysqli->connect_error property as in the preceding examples"_

Comment: Thanks, my info was outdated. I am not advocating mysqli by the way. My opinion depends on the goal. If you are looking for the API to build an abstraction class upon, to encapsulate all this weird bind_* stuff and call_user_func_arrays - mysqli I recommend. While if you you follow the common habit of using raw API functions in the application code, PDO would be the only sane choice.

Comment: You're welcome. And thank you for the _"relentless tough love"_ :P. I know you find quick, half arsed answers (like some of mine are) irritating. But I'd like to say that I'm not spiteful, and willing to learn more, as I am doing now (APC + `mysqli_result` looks promissing)